# Conditional formatting of footline, depending on whether footnotes are present

Tags: beamer, header-footer, footnotes

I know this question has been asked in a similar fashion before, but I have not seen an elegant solution using `\addtobeamertemplate` yet. I am using the beautiful `metropolis` style, in which the `footline` contains only the slide number in the very right corner. This leaves a lot of white space at the bottom. For most slides that is fine, but it looks a bit odd if I add the source of a data set into the `footnote`.

[image]

I would like to shift the footnote vertically. If I have a single `footnote` per slide, this can be accomplished very simply with the code:

```
\addtobeamertemplate{footnote}{}{\vskip-7mm}
```

Of couse it doesn't work for multiple footnotes on the same slide since the negative space is added for each `footnote`. I thought it should be simple enough to add negative space to the beginning of the `footline` template using a global `counter` that is set to `1`, whenever a footnote is added, and then set to `0` at the end of the slide. To my surprise, however, the following did not work:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[outer/progressbar=foot]{metropolis}

\newcount\footinput
\global\footinput 0\relax

\addtobeamertemplate{footnote}{}{\global\footinput 1\relax}

\addtobeamertemplate{footline}{%
\ifnum\footinput>0%
  \vskip-7mm%
  \global\footinput 0\relax%
\fi%
}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Important Findings}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Description of data set 1\footnote{Source of data set 1}
\item Description of data set 2\footnote{Source of data set 2}
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

What am I missing? The reason why I am surprised is that the `\footnoterule` is essentially defined in the same way in `beamerbaseframesize.sty` (using boxes instead of a counter).

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[outer/progressbar=foot]{metropolis}

\newcount\footinput
\global\footinput 0\relax

\addtobeamertemplate{footnote}{}{\global\footinput 1\relax}


\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\vspace{6.7pt}} 
\setbeamertemplate{logo}{%
\usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}%  
\usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}%   
\vspace{-7pt}   
\usebeamertemplate*{frame numbering}\hspace{5pt}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Important Findings}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Description of data set 1\footnote{Source of data set 1}
\item Description of data set 2%\footnote{Source of data set 2}
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Important Findings}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Description of data set 1\footnote{Source of data set 1}
\item Description of data set 2\footnote{Source of data set 2}
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: beamer footline]

Comment: I think this output is comparable to the simpler `\addtobeamertemplate{footline}{\vskip-7mm}{}`. It shifts the entire text downwards, even on slides where there is no footnote. I would like to leave the layout unaffected for slides without footnote.